# how to remove accidentally created ~ in my other linux directory while using wq~ in vi

Tags: linux

when I exit my vim, I accidentally typed wq~, and it created my home directory in my other linux directory which I am working on, anyway to remove it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quote it

```
rm '~'
```

You can also rename it to the name you want:

```
mv '~' correctname
```

Comment: Thanks!, it fixed it!